# Is "are dangerous" and "shown Boris Johnson" correct in this headline from the Daily Mirror?

Tags: british-english, headlinese

I cannot understand the "are dangerous" part and neither the "Shown Boris Johnson" part, I think they are incorrect.

> Kevin Maguire says "the reckless 'I don’t care, rules aren’t for me' approach" shown Boris Johnson, who was "sacked twice for deception", are dangerous for Britain [(Daily Mirror)](https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/politics/boris-johnson-charlatan-who-treats-23811927)

Answer (score 5):

It needs the word "by", and for agreement it should be "is dangerous"

> Kevin Maguire says "the reckless 'I don’t care, rules aren’t for me' approach" shown **by** Boris Johnson, who was "sacked twice for deception", **is** dangerous for Britain.

The structure is:

> Kevin says that (something) is dangerous.

The "something" is the "approach shown by Boris Johnson".  This means "The way Johnson solves a problem (ie the problem of running the government)".

His approach is described as being reckless etc.  And we are reminded in an aside that Johnson was twice sacked.